# Pixel Bender Chroma Keying code for flex3 / as3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3, pixel-bender, chromakey

Does anybody know where i can find a good chroma keying pixel bender code example.
Or does anybody know how to write such a code in pixel bender. Or a create pixel bender tutorial to create a chroma keying filter.
Does anybody know how to get it in flex 3.

every help is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple Difference Key pixel bender kernel:
http://code.google.com/p/quasimondolibs/source/browse/trunk/quasimondolibs/com/quasimondo/shaders/DifferenceKey.pbk

Comment: thank you Mr Quasimondo, i have also checked out your Realtime Video Color Keying. thanks again

Comment: hey quasimondo, I saw your realtime key color too and am looking for an AS3 solution. I just installed PB and your DifferenceKey.pbk. Do you have an example on your blog on using it?

Answer (score 1):

Yep http://code.google.com/p/quasimondolibs/source/browse/trunk/quasimondolibs/com/quasimondo/shaders/DifferenceKey.pbk by Quasimondo is perfect. Easy to build upon as well